# Flutter : How to stay logged in with MySQL

Tags: mysql, flutter

Hello I'm new to flutter , I'm using MySQL with the application and I want to keep the  user logged in after re-opening the application , I've tried to use shared preferences and to be honest I got stuck and did not know what to do ,  here is my code for the login page , so what should I do in this case ?

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:data_connection_checker/data_connection_checker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_custom_clippers/flutter_custom_clippers.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:giffy_dialog/giffy_dialog.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:rounded_loading_button/rounded_loading_button.dart';
String email = '';
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  final RoundedLoadingButtonController _btnController = RoundedLoadingButtonController();
  TextEditingController email = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController pass = TextEditingController();

  void _btndo () async{
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 4),(){
      _btnController.success();
      _login();
    });
  }

  Future<List> _login() async {
    final response = await http.post("http://msc-mu.com/login_app.php", body: {
      "email": email.text,
      "password": pass.text,
    });
    var userdata = json.decode(response.body);
    if (userdata == 0) {
      setState(() {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: 'Login Failed',
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
            backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 16.0);
      });
    } else {
      if (userdata[0]['type'] == 'Admin') {
        setState(() {
          Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/Admin');
        });
      } else if (userdata[0]['type'] == 'Student') {
        setState(() {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/Student');
        });
      } else if (userdata[0]['type'] == 'Representative') {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/Representative');
      }
    }
    return userdata;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    var listener = DataConnectionChecker();
    listener.onStatusChange.listen((status) {
      switch (status) {
        case DataConnectionStatus.connected:
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: 'connected',
              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
              gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
              timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 16.0);
          break;
        case DataConnectionStatus.disconnected:
          showDialog(
              barrierDismissible: false,
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => AssetGiffyDialog(
                image: Image.asset('images/wait_connection.gif'),
                title: Text(
                  'Sorry !! , But You Are Not Connected',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 22.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
                description: Text(
                  'Our App Require internet connection , Can you please Reconnect and try again by pressing OK  ?',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                entryAnimation: EntryAnimation.TOP_RIGHT,
                onlyOkButton: true,
                onOkButtonPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    void check() async {
                      try {
                        final result =
                        await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
                        if (result.isNotEmpty &&
                            result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
                          Navigator.pop(context, true);
                          Fluttertoast.showToast(
                              msg: 'connected Again',
                              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                              gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                              timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                              textColor: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 16.0);
                        }
                      } on SocketException catch (_) {
                        Fluttertoast.showToast(
                            msg: 'Still not connected',
                            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                            gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 16.0);
                      }
                    }
                    check();
                  });
                },
              ));
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ClipPath(
                clipper: OvalBottomBorderClipper(),
                child: Image(
                  image: AssetImage('images/logo1.png'),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.9,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 50.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: email,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                      fillColor: Colors.transparent,
                      filled: true,
                      hintText: 'Email Address',
                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                        FontAwesomeIcons.mailBulk,
                        size: 30.0,
                      )),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 50.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  controller: pass,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                      fillColor: Colors.transparent,
                      filled: true,
                      hintText: 'Password',
                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                        FontAwesomeIcons.key,
                        size: 30.0,
                      )),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              RoundedLoadingButton(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                child: Text('Login',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                controller: _btnController,
                onPressed: _btndo,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to implement the following process:

1. Once a user logs in, you can generate a token and store it in MySQL database and share the same token with the response of login API.
2. Store the token using shared-preferences.
3. When a user opens the app, check if the token exists if it does, then send the token with all the APIs inside the request header which requires the user to be logged in.
4. You can set an expiry time of each token and check the request header if it contains token and if the token is valid or not. 
   (i). If the token is valid then return the required data based on other validations.
   (ii) If not return an error code/message and take the user to the login screen

The code you shared, has only a login feature. You need to implement the above approach.